Active Storage Image Uploading. Cannot seem to display image? 404 Not Found Error
My images that are uploaded through Active Storage are not being displayed properly. After checking the instance, I found out that the image_blob is being created and the image data is being attached. However, the image is still not displaying.
Model.rb
 has_one_attached :work_image
 has_one_attached :proposal_image
 has_one_attached :development_image
 has_one_attached :design_image
 has_one_attached :result_image
 has_one_attached :client_voice_image
 has_one_attached :additional_section_image
 has_one_attached :additional_section2_image

Needs to be several has_one_attached because the each image has to be in a specific place when they are shown
Controller.rb
def new
  @work = Work.new
end

def submit
  @work = Work.new(work_params) # 新規のWorkインスタンスを作成
  if @work.save # ワークを保存
    process_tags
    redirect_to preview_admin_work_path(@work)
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def preview
  @work = Work.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
...
private

def work_params
    params.require(:work).permit(
      :work_image,
      :work_title,
      :release_date,
      :client_name,
      :service_name,
      :service_url,
         ......
      :development_image,
      :proposal_image,
      :design_image,
      :result_image,
      :client_voice_image,
      :additional_section_image,
      :additional_section2_image,
      tag_ids: []
    )
end
def process_tags
  if params[:work][:tag_ids].present?
    tag_ids = if params[:work][:tag_ids].is_a?(Array)
                params[:work][:tag_ids].map(&:to_i)
              else
                params[:work][:tag_ids].split(',').map(&:to_i)
              end
    @work.tags = Tag.where(id: tag_ids)
  end
end

Viewfile (new.html.erb)
<%= form_for @work, url: submit_admin_works_path, local: true, multipart: true do |f| %>
....
    <div class="mt-3">
      <%= f.label :work_image, "サムネイル画像を登録<span class='required'>   ※必須</span>".html_safe, class: "form-label" %>
      <%= f.file_field :work_image, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
....
<% end %>

show(edit) is almost the same with just the form url difference
Viewfile (preview.html.erb)
...
<%= image_tag @work.work_image, alt: 'Work Image' %>  
...


Trying to parse through the rant -- not clear what problem you are trying to solve.  Please clarify what your current issue i.

update the question - don't bury information in comments
